# Is there any easy tool to load CSVs into PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, csv, load

Is there any easy tool to load CSVs into PostgreSQL? 
I know there's the POSTGIS DBF loader tool but I was wondering if there's any non-commercial or commercial add-on that allows one to easily load in a CSV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`COPY` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html), built-in to PostgreSQL, does exactly what you want. It's most useful when used in its `\copy` variant via `psql`.

Check the documentation for your particular Pg version, as `COPY` options vary. In future please mention your Pg version when posting. Assuming you're on 9.1, then from a `psql` client cou could use:

```
\copy target_table from 'the_file.csv' with (format csv)
```

and possibly other options, as documented in the link above, depending on the details of your CSV dialect.

Note that the `\copy` command will *not* work from PgAdmin-III or other clients; it's specific to `psql`. Regular `COPY` works from any client, but requires that the file be accessible by the database *server*'s `postgres` process, so it's much less convenient.

You can also use [`pg_bulkload`](http://pgbulkload.projects.postgresql.org/) or ETL tools like Talend and Pentaho if the job is huge or more complicated.

Comment: If the file is several gigs with ~ 120 columns would pg_bulkload be the right approach?  Apologies for the delay in response!

Comment: @user1397044 Hard to say. If time isn't critical I'd probably use a server-side `COPY` from a file local to the server.